# inline-table and inline-block issues in IE and FF

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

[image: my div in chrome]

I have 4 inline-block divs inside a block div. As you can see they look OK in Chrome. Looks OK in Opera as well. However, when I see same div in IE and FF it looks like this:

[image: my div in IE]

I have tried several tricks like `display:inline` or `zoom:1` but nothing have helped so far.

Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwqYYz?editors=110). Check it out with IE and FF to see the problem.

Here is the exact css code of each inline divs which you see in image as well:

```
#win_logo_1{
    width:46px;
    height:46px;
    background-position:-229px -151px;
    background-image:url(http://topdesignstudio.ir/img/icons/icon_sheet.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, put the code into the question; the codepen helps, but it's best to have the code inline with the question as well. Secondly, try to reduce the question (ie the code) down to the minimum example needed to demonstrate the problem. There should be as little code as possible. Finally, be clear about what the problem is: just saying "none of 'em worked" isn't a good enough description. In what way is it not working? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing or vice versa? What were the tricks you tried? Did some of them work better than others?

Comment: As well is this happening on any Ie browsers or is version specific?

Comment: I have checked it on IE 11, I don't know about other versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all I have a good solution for this.
First I used inline-table instead of inline-block for each box of my win logo.
Second I increase the width of winLogo (parent of four box) a bit.
Third I detect whether if it's IE then I remove maigin-left of my win_logo_2 nad 4.
Here is [`Codepen`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdmYvr) Which works OK on IE.
Still working on FF and Safari